# Getting AIR stacktraces in ipad for release build

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Is there any way of getting full stacktraces for an AIR application in Release build running in devices (ipad / iphone)?

I tried as mentioned in the link:-
http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/stack-traces-in-release-build

http://renaun.com/blog/2012/09/getting-the-stack-trace-in-a-release-flash-player/

It seems we are able to get traces only in Flash Player not in the device

I also tried placing a debug file in app AIR directory.

This works fine for windows application. Could not able to find any way making this work in devices (ipad / iphone)?

I am not able to get the full stack trace Using UncaughtErrorHandler also

Any paid solution is also OK.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999626/can-i-build-a-debug-version-of-an-adobe-air-application/14000013#14000013

Comment: Try Adobe Scout and advanced telemetry from https://www.adobe.com/products/gaming/tools.html