# getting the stack trace of a flash application when running without the debugger

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stack-trace

I'm trying to create a crash report for my application. Getting the stack trace is easy when the game is running with debug: it is included in the Error object that is created in the crash. but when running with no debug, this information is missing.

Is there any way to get this information?

Comment: The documentation says: "For Flash Player 11.4 and earlier and AIR 3.4 and earlier, stack traces are **only** available when code is running in the debugger version of Flash Player or the AIR Debug Launcher (ADL). In non-debugger versions of those runtimes, calling this method returns null." Maybe try targeting a newer version of Flash Player or AIR and see if that works?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999626/can-i-build-a-debug-version-of-an-adobe-air-application/14000013#14000013 - question talks about AIR but applies to FlashPlayer too

Comment: Short answer: Not working. I have been trying this for a while and works only in debug mode. Also you could manually specify the class/line where this occurs but that is soooo ugly and unprofessional (also any code change requires updates) so I do not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try-catch blocks in suspicious places of your app.

```
try {
    ExternalInterface.call('conf', 4);
    ExternalInterface.addCallback('transcodeReqAnswer', analyseTranscodeAnswer);
} catch(er:Error) {
    debugTextField.text = er.getStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: this will work correct only in debug mode, in release versions you will get just error name

Comment: try...catch is very heavy on the processor, too. You should avoid using it in release versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling in debug mode you have to pass the parameters to javascript through ExternalInterface. Then you should be able to see the stacktrace from the console output of your browser.

Example:

```
flash.system.Security.allowDomain(sourceDomain)
ExternalInterface.call("print", error.getStackTrace());
```

and in JavaScript there should be a function

```
function takeLog(string) {
    console.log("stacktrace: " + string);
}
```

In non-debug mode the getStackTrace() function returns null.

More information in the official documentation,
[ExternalInterface.call()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call%28%29),
[getStackTrace()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html#getStackTrace%28%29)